# Scrape a site content With a Secure Login

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the contents of the a site with login secured 
but unable to do it 
The site's login has three options username,password,passcode
here is the code I am using

```
<?php

// HTTP authentication

$url = "http://aftabcurrency.com/login_script.php";

$ch = curl_init();    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user_name=user&user_password=pass&passcode=code");             

$result = curl_exec($ch); 

curl_close($ch); 

echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: i tried this code with changes you accepted in the answer, but this code is not working for me, i am using my amazon seller account's details but nothing is happening, can you guide me something as i am new to PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to do a `POST` to http://aftabcurrency.com/login_script.php
your curl needs also to accept cookies.
After the authentification the script will redirect you, so you need also to add **CURLOPT_FOLLOWACTION**.

here is a edited version of your script, I can't test it on http://aftabcurrency.com/ hope it works:

```
$url = "http://aftabcurrency.com/login_script.php";

$ch = curl_init();    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
$cookie = 'cookies.txt';
$timeout = 30;

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,         10); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,  $timeout );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,       $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,      $cookie);

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"user_name=user&user_password=pass&passcode=code");     

$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* //OPTIONAL - Redirect to another page after login
$url = "http://aftabcurrency.com/some_other_page";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
 */ //end OPTIONAL 

curl_close($ch); 
echo $result;
```

Comment: here I edited your code, in your cookie part you did set a wrong variable ($curl and not $ch) - and also I added CURLOPT_FOLLOWACTION so the script can redirect you after login.

Comment: Thanks it works
What If I want to scrape a particular "text" from that page
for example in http://aftabcurrency.com/ I only wish to scrap only 
"Our Services Matters!" (this text changes every day)
any Idea ?

Comment: there are a lot ways to scrape html content:  php string search functions, regex, dom / simplexml (xpath)...

Comment: can u give me a short hint or a link to any tutorial ?

Comment: Can u tell me how to do it through curl
I mean how do integrate in above codes ?

Comment: I have found a code on this site http://www.digeratimarketing.co.uk/2008/12/16/curl-page-scraping-script/
but unable to integrate it into the above mentioned code

Comment: open a new question here on stackoverflow, i cant write here a code because i can write only 500 characters.. ;) or search for it on stack overflow - use keywords: php scraping, personally i would do this by xpath (simplexml).

Comment: I have opened a new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184447/scrape-a-particular-area-of-site-content-with-a-secure-login

Comment: – qxxx can u please answer the new question I have given above ?

Comment: I added some OPTIONAL code to show how to redirect to another page on the same site after you have logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to POST your username/password/passcode to that page. What you are trying to do right now is http authentication.
So instead of this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "demo:demopass:demopasscode");
```

you need this

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user_name=xxxxx&user_password=xxxxxx&passcode=xxxxx");
```