# Scrape Aliexpress Logged page for retrieve tracking information using CURL

Tags: php, parsing, curl, screen-scraping, scrape

I am trying to scrape a login protected page to retrieve product tracking information with CURL but currently unsuccessful.

I have followed several guides/tutorials like this one:
[Scrape a site content With a Secure Login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171713/scrape-a-site-content-with-a-secure-login)

The page I need to scrape on is as follows:
https://track.aliexpress.com/logisticsdetail.htm?spm=a2g0o.order_detail.0.0.4bae582fjE9xlW&tradeId=3017113865919547

Obviously if you try to log in it will take you to the aliexpress login page: https://aliexpress.com

I modified the code and now my code is as follows:

```
        $url = "https://track.aliexpress.com/logisticsdetail.htm?spm=a2g0o.order_detail.0.0.4bae582fjE9xlW&tradeId=3017214707579547";

//last number is the ID of aliexpress order 
    
    
    $pars=array(
        'fm-login-id' => 'myemail',
        'fm-login-password' => 'mypassword'
    );
    
    
    
    $ch = curl_init();    
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$pars);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    
    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    
    
    curl_close($ch); 
    echo $result;
```

I changed the user and password names to their "name" fields in the form. What's wrong with it?

Comment: _"but currently unsuccessful."_ - Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72912345/edit) your post to add a proper explanation of the issue. Just saying it's "unsuccessful" doesn't really give us anything to go on. What _exactly_ happens when you run your code? Errors? Unexpected/invalid response? Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: I would think it would be easier to use their [api](https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=108970&docType=1) instead of trying to scrape a webpage. Web logins are not straightforward, and often involve session variables that you cannot mimic with cURL. APIs use authentication tokens that can be used for each request.